# IDEA 11 adb I/O error when trying to attach a debugger when 2 IDEA's windows open

Tags: android, intellij-idea

At this moment, this error started with IDEA 11. I still did not find the right pattern but if a device or emulator are idle for a specific period of time (not long) and if I then try to push the project to a device/emulator and to attach a debugger, first appears a message that IDEA is trying to connect to ADB (a several message windows) and then the upload starts, the apps gets uploaded, then it fails with error:

```
Launching application: com.xxx/com.xxx.sMain.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.xxx/com.xxx.Main"
I/O Error: Connection refused
```

The only solution is to close both emulator and IDEA or to disconnect a real device from USB cable.

Any ideas why this is happening? As I said it happened with both device and emulator so I cannot tell that it's up to a device/emulator.

**EDIT**

I tried restarting ADB via shell, it did not help either. This does not happen when I simply `run` the project, but only when I press `debug`.

**EDIT 2 (18May)**

I've noticed that this is happening when **two IDEA's screens** are opened in the same time. For example, I open another project and choose to open it in new window. I first run the app in window 1, and then in window 2, but then the popup "Trying to attach to ADB" keeps opening and closing. I see that memory increases for a couple of MB as each time a new popup is created. this leads to IDEA stop responding and I have to kill it.

I think this is a new bug.